# Default TreeView item height

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, treeview

In my program, there are two controls - native TreeView and managed DataGridView. I want to set the `RowsHeight` property for the DataGridView with TreeView item height, but unfortunately the TreeView don't have an option to retrive the height. Then I tried to use `GetTextMetric` function and set the `RowsHeight` to the `tmHeight` value. Unfortunately it's still don't work - the height of the DataGridView items is bigger than the TreeView ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the [`TVM_GETITEMHEIGHT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773599.aspx) to the control to get the item height.